# React Module not found

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have installed an npm package on my react application but everytime I try to compile I get this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'serialport' in 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\ProjectGroup\c-test\src'
```

I have checked the node_modules folder and it is in fact in that folder.
i have also tried to install it again but it still throws the same error.
How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: How did you import it? What's your project's root path, and in which file did you import it ? Also, in which path (where) did you install it ?

Comment: can you show us the import ?

Comment: the install was npm i @types/serialport
The import was 
import SerialPort from 'serialport';
the projects root path is in the post(the root is c-test)
I imported it into App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

As shown in comments, you installed only the `types` which are usefull for TypeScript.

Run `npm i serialport`

Comment: I did this and now I get a bunch of other errors

mostly Module not found again but now insidee the serialport
Example:
ERROR in ./node_modules/@serialport/parser-delimiter/dist/index.js 7:17-34

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\ProjectGroup\c-test\node_modules\@serialport\parser-delimiter\dist'